# Proving the Increase of $(a+\delta)_m - (a)_m$ Given Decrease of $\frac{(a+\delta)_m}{(a)_m}$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, convexity-inequality

The question I'm struggling with is as follows:

> Let $a>0$ and $\delta > 0$ (fixed). Suppose $ a \mapsto \frac{(a+\delta)_{m}}{(a)_{m}}$  is decreasing then prove that $ a \mapsto (a+\delta)_{m} - (a)_{m} $ is increasing ( means Wright convex).

I'm reading a paper in which the authors have given no reason for this. I have tried by taking $b>a$ and tried to show that  $(a+\delta)_{m} - (a)_{m} < (b+\delta)_{m} - (b)_{m} $ using $\frac{(a+\delta)_{m}}{(a)_{m}} > \frac{(b+\delta)_{m}}{(b)_{m}}$ (decreasing). I have getting $(a+\delta)_{m} - (a)_{m} - (b+\delta)_{m} + (b)_{m} > \text{something} $. I can't get the answer to this. I guess there is something related to increasing and decreasing functions. I'm not getting an idea how to proceed.

Comment: What is $(a)_m$?

Comment: @daw Pochhammer's Symbol. $(a)_n = (a)(a+1) \dots (a+n-1)$.

Comment: Are there any conditions missing? I see that for $\delta = -1.5$ and $m=3$, $\frac{(x+\delta)_m}{(x)_m}$ is decreasing in $(0,0.5)$ and $(x+\delta)_m -(x)_m$ is also decreasing.

Comment: @YathirajSharma. Yes missed $\delta > 0 $. Added it in main question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $m>0$, suppose $x>0$ and $\delta>0$. Define
$$h(x)= \frac{(x+\delta)_m}{(x)_m}.$$
Let, for the sake of convenience, $f(x) = (x+\delta)_m$ and $g(x) = (x)_m$. I now see that there is an extra information in your problem statement which was unnecessary. I see that with $\delta>0$, $h(x)$ is decreasing for $x>0$. To see this, logarithmically differentiate $h(x)$ to get,

$$h^{\prime}(x) = -\delta h(x) \left(\frac{1}{x(x+\delta)}+\dots+\frac{1}{(x+\delta+n-1)(x+n-1)}\right).$$

$h(x)$ is anyway positive. So, $h^{\prime}(x)$ is negative and hence $h$ is decreasing.

Quite clearly

$$f^{\prime}(x) = \frac{f(x)}{x+\delta}+\frac{f(x)}{x+\delta+1}+\dots+\frac{f(x)}{x+\delta+n-1}.$$

And

$$g^{\prime}(x) =  \frac{g(x)}{x}+\frac{g(x)}{x+1}+\dots+\frac{g(x)}{x+n-1}.$$

Further, it is easy to see by the definitions of $f$ and $g$ that

$$\frac{f(x)}{x+\delta+k}-\frac{g(x)}{x+k} \geq 0,$$
whenever $k\geq 0$.

Thus

$$f^{\prime}(x) \geq g^{\prime}(x),$$
indicating that $f(x)-g(x)$ is increasing.